# Load testing Bot builder bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, load-testing

## Update

Using emulator as channelId and updating to SDK 3.13.1 works for me.

---

- App ID: 8c082f92-fb38-4841-a29f-339eb315f7aa
- SDK Platform: Node.js
- SDK Version: 3.13.1
- Active Channels: Facebook
- Deployment Environment: ngrok

### Issue Description

I tried following steps mentioned in [this link](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/load-testing-a-bot/). This has two parts. One is creating the token and second is to send a message to the bot. POSTMAN request leads to 500 Internal Server Error and ERROR: ChatConnector: receive - invalid signing key or OpenId metadata document in the code.

### Code Example

1. Create token

   ```
    curl -X POST  https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token   -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  -H 'postman-token: 792660ab-b1aa-0cbd-edab-9b3847c170d5'  -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=8c082f92-fb38-4841-a29f-339eb315f7aa&client_secret=vxcihBT2679%7C(%23puEXBPT1!&scope=8c082f92-fb38-4841-a29f-339eb315f7aa%2F.default'
   ```
2. Send a message

   ```
    curl -X POST https://1c36f336.ngrok.io/api/messages -H 'authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ing0Nzh4eU9wbHNNMUg3TlhrN1N4MTd4MXVwYyJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI4YzA4MmY5Mi1mYjM4LTQ4NDEtYTI5Zi0zMzllYjMxNWY3YWEiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vZDZkNDk0MjAtZjM5Yi00ZGY3LWExZGMtZDU5YTkzNTg3MWRiL3YyLjAiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTIxOTg2NjcsIm5iZiI6MTUxMjE5ODY2NywiZXhwIjoxNTEyMjAyNTY3LCJhaW8iOiJZMk5nWUZEOHRySzgvZk9XcDF2L1BMM2JibnRGRGdBPSIsImF6cCI6IjhjMDgyZjkyLWZiMzgtNDg0MS1hMjlmLTMzOWViMzE1ZjdhYSIsImF6cGFjciI6IjEiLCJ0aWQiOiJkNmQ0OTQyMC1mMzliLTRkZjctYTFkYy1kNTlhOTM1ODcxZGIiLCJ1dGkiOiJXLWdYbXpPSkxVYWdzSFZUbXBJd0FBIiwidmVyIjoiMi4wIn0.G705tzQIU5Mh6IROtXkIwm8Q9AKZ_q-VOtJuuozqP-ekhWoKc0HpcdhgBlnaMsMHKoM0RWhUlXn27xCfK46vEE9IZlkjcAh7huhvlWNtW8IP5w7QiL3JCSTYKCtBXZq-VKeWctNWR9M8Y9Ry4dyiEdcDMcHWrbOUqR6nXvlwG76GSR4YilqzMWdSW6t5Pep3hwOw07DSargYP0pDAnWAg3pWHnhcJ185533I1VVXEIuc_CK-RmP9qhUAScEbYkpp_7l75bVWzxKv-3E1UOG4SBj6UzfH47X5kwz_njn1kAJcrqBvP3s_CjS4qUdDSNARtxGZ3UQWj49UBKosqar0dg' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'postman-token: 3a74ce00-2da7-d674-5e4c-083f54ed30ff' -d '{ "type": "message", "id": "mid.$cAAGEkG8MNm1mOEBe-lgBvsWZbQUc", "channelId" : "test",  "conversation": { "id": "100023023852067-526013297749070"}, "from": { "id": "100023023852067" }, "recipient": { "id": "526013297749070" },  "serviceUrl": "https://1c36f336.ngrok.io", "text": "Hi message from postman !!!" }'
   ```

### Reproduction Steps

1. Using the two curl requests mentioned above. This should lead to the mentioned issue.

### Expected Behavior

POSTMAN request should lead to 202 Accepted and bot receiving the message. Am I missing something or is there something wrong in the process? I saw [some](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3232)  [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3510)  on load testing but none of them helped.

### Actual Results

POSTMAN request leads to 500 Internal Server Error and ERROR: ChatConnector: receive - invalid signing key or OpenId metadata document in the code.

Comment: @nils-w Any comments ?

Comment: @user:5199616 Any comments ?

Comment: I can see your app id & app secret, you might want to remove it

Comment: @KienChu Thanks for pointing it. This is just a test bot. So it's fine. By the way how do people using botbuilder framework do load testing? I am really stuck now.

Comment: Please try updating your sdk version. https://blog.botframework.com/2017/05/07/bot-framework-auth-change/  UPDATED 08/08/2017: We revised our security protocols on July 31, 2017. Update to Bot Builder 3.9+ or compatible security configuration to keep your bot working

Comment: What happens after you upgrade your `botbuilder` module to `3.13.1`? Do you see the same errors?

Comment: Also - ngrok isn't going to be the best way to load test, unless you have a paid plan, since ngrok-free tier has request throttling in place.

Comment: @nilsw Agreed , right now we are just trying to get some testing code ready on test bots. The actual webhooks are not ngrok based.

Comment: @EricDahlvang I will try this and update you.

Comment: @EricDahlvang Tried with module 3.13.1 . Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work after:

1) adding a custom state client to the bot using botbuilder-azure

2) exposing the message sink, for receiving the bot response

3) changing the channelId to "emulator" (apparently node sdk doesn't handle 'test' channel)

```
curl -X POST  https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MyMicrosoftAppId&client_secret=MyMicrosoftAppPassword&scope=MyMicrosoftAppId%2F.default"

curl -X POST https://e84a2f49.ngrok.io/api/messages -H "authorization: Bearer TokenFromPreviousCall" -d "{ \"type\": \"message\", \"id\": \"mid.$cAAGEkG8MNm1mOEBe-lgBvsWZbQUc\", \"channelId\" : \"emulator\",  \"conversation\": { \"id\": \"100023023852067-526013297749070\"}, \"from\": { \"id\": \"100023023852067\" }, \"recipient\": { \"id\": \"526013297749070\" },  \"serviceUrl\": \"https://e84a2f49.ngrok.io\", \"text\": \"Hi message from postman !!!\" }"
```

Here is the app, for reference:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var azure = require('botbuilder-azure');

var sqlConfig = {
    userName: 'SqlServerUserId',
    password: 'SqlServerPassword',
    server: 'mySqlServer.net',
    enforceTable: true, 
    options: {
        database: 'BotDatabaseName',
        table: 'BotDataTableName',
        encrypt: true,
        rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true
    }
}

var sqlClient = new azure.AzureSqlClient(sqlConfig);
var sqlStorage = new azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, sqlClient);

var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3980, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: "MyAppId",
    appPassword: "MyAppPassword" 
});

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
}).set('storage', sqlStorage);;

//message sink 
server.post("/v3/conversations/:conversationId/activities/:activityId", function(Request, Response, next) {
    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The channelId was the missing part. The documentation should be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but *if* you're using the same "fromId" in every request for your load test, it might be relevant.

Previously I've had a similar issue that required me to use a unique "fromId" in each request, else a series of requests in rapid succession start to fail.

I raised this issue on github, and although it says "followed up offline" and "problem was with the bot code", it was actually due to using the same "fromId" in every request.

The issue is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1176

Comment: Your situation is quite different from mine. As I can see in my case its more related to the authentication. Also, I am unable to send even one message. But anyways thanks for pointing this.

Answer (score 1):

After I added `extended` field I got same error.
Not sure how that is related but replace

```
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

to:

```
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

fixed the issue.